# Jquery image slider won't work propperly

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Hello I'm using this plug in :https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-tiles
for creating an image slider in header of my website. I'm using Asp.net MVC.
unfortunately the slider wont work as like as demo. instead of showing one row and one column it shows the slider in 2 columns and x rows (x is the number of images i use in my slider.

this is my index cshtml code :

```
 @{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<link href="~/Content/jquery.tiles.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.tiles.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
    <img src="~/Content/img/img01.jpg" /> <!-- No description -->
    <img src="~/Content/img/img02.jpg" /> <!-- No description -->
    <img src="~/Content/img/img03.jpg" /> <!-- No description -->
    <img src="~/Content/img/img04.jpg" /> <!-- No description -->
    <img src="~/Content/img/img05.jpg" /> <!-- No description -->
    <img src="~/Content/img/img06.jpg" /> <!-- No description -->
    <img src="~/Content/img/img07.jpg" /> <!-- No description -->
    <img src="~/Content/img/img08.jpg" /> <!-- No description -->
    <img src="~/Content/img/img09.jpg" /> <!-- No description -->
    <img src="~/Content/img/img10.jpg" /> <!-- No description -->
</div>


<script>

    $('.slider').tilesSlider({
        x: 15, // # of tiles in x axis, 20 max
        y: 10, // # of tiles in y axis, 20 max
        effect: 'simple',
        fade: false, // fade images in addition to the tiles effect
        random: true, // animate tiles in random order
        reverse: false, // start animation from opposite direction
        backReverse: false, // reverse the animation when going back in the slideshow (useful for some effects)
        rewind: false, // reverse animation at a certain percentage in time
        auto: true, // Start the slideshow on load
        loop: true, // Start slideshow again when it finishes
        slideSpeed: 3500, // time between slides
        tileSpeed: 800, // time to clear all tiles
        cssSpeed: 300, // css3 transition speed [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000],
        nav: false, // Add navigation
        navWrap: null, // Add the navigation to an existing element
        bullets: false, // Show bullets, if false the show pagination with numbers
        thumbs: false, // Show thumbnails when hovering nav
        thumbSize: 25, // Thumbnail size (percentage of the original image)
        timer: false // show or hide the timer bar

    });



</script>
```

The animation and transitions works just fine the only problem is the repeating of image as shown in figure:[image: pic1]

Comment: This is a CSS issue. Go ahead and use the dev tools to know how to write the right CSS to fix the slider sizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set carousel item wrapper style as `background-repeat: no-repeat`